# NameError: name 'Ptime' is not defined using tkinter scale scroller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a function to modify the timecode shift of a script for instant replay, but when I create the function including the variable mentioned by Tkinter, I'm getting a name not defined error. I used a software called "PAGE" to create the GUI so I really have a very basic knowledge of tkinter. I'm not quite sure what code I need to include so I'm just going to paste all of the function definition and the entire support script generated by PAGE

I moved all of my function definitions into the support script but to no avail

```
def set_Tk_var():
    global Ptime
    Ptime = tk.DoubleVar()
    global Pspeed
    Pspeed = tk.StringVar()

text = "play: timecode: 00:00:0" + str(Ptime) + ";00 \\nc"
def IRplay():
    print('testguiPAGE_support.IRplay')
    session.write(b"stop\n")
    session.write( text.encode() )
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

in the main script the only place it's being referred to is:

```
def vp_start_gui():
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    testguiPAGE_support.set_Tk_var()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    testguiPAGE_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()


w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    testguiPAGE_support.set_Tk_var()
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    testguiPAGE_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)
```

getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\InstSmart\Desktop\Rplay\Outputs\testguiPAGE.py", line 23, in <module>
    import testguiPAGE_support
  File "C:\Users\InstSmart\Desktop\Rplay\Outputs\testguiPAGE_support.py", line 40, in <module>
    text = "play: timecode: 00:00:0" + str(Ptime) + ";00 \\nc"
NameError: name 'Ptime' is not defined
```

if there is anymore info you need, comment it, and I will add to the question

Comment: when you import a module, inline codes get executed. So, after importing `testguiPAGE_support`, `text` is going to be defined, but `Ptime` is not defined.

Comment: Any ideas on how to remedy the issue?

Comment: Its a complicated and incomplete snippet. I think defining `text = "play: tim...` in `IRplay()`, can solve it.

Comment: That partially worked... But now I need to turn the string into an integer